# unmappable character for encoding utf8

Tags: java, maven

While building a project using maven. I am getting this error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project uidai-auth-client: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /uidai-auth-client-1.6-src/uidai-auth-client/src/main/java/in/gov/uidai/auth/aua/httpclient/NamespaceFilter.java:[91,44] error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project uidai-auth-client: Compilation failure
/uidai-auth-client-1.6-src/uidai-auth-client/src/main/java/in/gov/uidai/auth/aua/httpclient/NamespaceFilter.java:[91,44] error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/uidai-auth-client-1.6-src/uidai-auth-client/src/main/java/in/gov/uidai/auth/aua/httpclient/NamespaceFilter.java:[91,44] error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR]
```

Can any one help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Look at NamespaceFilter.java:[91,44]. I suspect that `NamespaceFilter.java` isn't UTF-8 encoded, so you should specify the *actual* encoding to the compiler.

Comment: Another option is to not use characters which need mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your source file has an encoding which is not UTF-8.

Find out what encoding it is (say ISO-8859-1) and then specify the encoding in your POM like this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

It is good practice to always specify the encoding explicitly, to avoid depending on the platform encoding (i.e. operating system defaults). Maven will print a warning otherwise.